# VPS hostname, ns1 and ns2 prefix

Tags: vps, hostname

Sorry for the stupid question. I'm completely new to servers in general and I want to sign up for a **VPS**.

On the sign-up page, I have to fill in these fields:

[image]

I have no idea what I should write into these fields (apart from password obviously), and there's no help tips in the site...

Note that I don't have a domain, and in fact I don't want to buy any if it's not necessary...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is something that should have been asked of the hosting provider's support team. 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are standardised WHMCS fields; just fill in the hostname ("computer name") you want your server to have (doesn't have to have a full domain, really) and anything you want on the other two fields (ns1/ns2 would be fine as dummy values) - I'd be surprised if they use the NS1/NS2 fields at all unless you were ordering a domain name at the same time.

They might not even set the hostname on the server, but may use the hostname field for the reverse dns of your VPS's IP (but also, again, probably not) - it's difficult to say. For example, we use WHMCS, but any process involving hostnames, reverse dns etc would be manual anyway - and that's not all that uncommon.

Comment: Thanks @Phil, but could you explain in a bit more detail why I can write any hostname and what happens with that hostname actually (i.e., what it will be used for)?

Comment: The hostname is the name of "the computer" - in this case, of the vps.

Comment: The host may also use the hostname to set the reverse DNS on your IP - eg, when you look up a domain or host on the internet (such as www.google.com for example) you get an IP address. "Reverse DNS" refers to - literally - the reverse of that process, so looking up an IP address to get (often) the hostname of the server at that IP. Long story short - if you don't know what a hostname is (and don't want to register/do anything with domain names) you probably don't need to really worry too much about it - the provider *should* set something sane by default.

Comment: On reflection; really, you should be asking the prospective supplier. It's their job to tell you what to fill in here and guide you on how exactly they'll use this information - and if they aren't answering your queries satisfactorily, then you should choose another host.